# Integrals involving $1/|\zeta(1+i t)|^2$: closed expressions?

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta-function

Is there by any chance anything resembling a closed expression for, say, the integral
$$I = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{|\zeta(1+i t)|^2 t^2} ?$$
It is easy to show (by Plancherel) that
$$I = \int_0^\infty |m(x)|^2 \frac{d x}{x}$$
for $m(x):=\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)/n$, but I'd like to know whether there is something "more closed" than that.

Comment: Note that this has been crossposted to MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4234446/9754

Comment: (Should I have stated that, and, if so, how?)

Comment: Generally I'd recommend choosing the site that seems like the best fit and just posting it there. (In this case, that seems like MO). If that doesn't yield answers after a bit, then perhaps ask somewhere else and link between them. This is basically [what's recommended here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/205676). Some people are really sensitive to people posting the same question on different forums, thinking that they're quickly trying to get an answer and not worrying that this might encourage duplication of effort.

Comment: About the question itself: it might be possible to adapt some of the work of [KST](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s006050200031) (or earlier related work by Perelli) to get a related expression with $\sum \mu^2(n)/n$ appearing, but maybe this is also not very closed. It seems hard for me to imagine an expression without some sum over $\mu(n)$ appearing.

Comment: Well, this one seems like a toss-up between the two sites, so I let the universe decide.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Interesting - what do you have in mind? A single sum would probably count as "closed enough".

Comment: Making some transformations from the integral, transformations that I will be ashamed to confess, I get to this expression
$$-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\Bigl(\sum_{ab=n}\mu(a)\mu(b)|\log(a/b)|\Bigr).$$
Numerically it appear to have some sense.

Comment: Given that the finiteness of this integral implies the prime number theorem, it is unlikely that there is going to be a closed form for this expression that is manifestly finite without the assistance of this theorem, unless you are willing to allow expressions that depend on the location of the zeroes of the zeta function as a "closed form".

Comment: Well, do you have some such expressions?

Comment: Sure, but they are pretty disgusting: you've already basically expressed your integral in terms of the (logarithmically weighted) Mertens function, and that function can be written (assuming simple zeroes) as a sum over zeroes (but with coefficients that are reciprocals of products of differences of zeroes, so not super pleasant to deal with).  After interchanging some sums you should be able to write your expression as a sum over pairs of zeroes of some nasty product over zeroes.  Can't say that this will be too enlightening, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not properly an answer,
after the comments of Tao it is difficult to give an answer. Only an explanation of my comment above. I still think that my series  and the integral are equal.

We can write the integral $I$ in the form
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\zeta(1+it)\zeta(1-it)}\frac{dt}{t^2}.$$
Hence I consider the function
$$u(\sigma)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma+it)\zeta(\sigma-it)}\frac{dt}{(\sigma-1)^2+t^2},\qquad \sigma>1.$$
I expect to have $\lim_{\sigma\to1^+}u(\sigma)=I$. For $\sigma>1$ we may write
$$u(\sigma)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{(ab)^\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(b/a)^{it}\frac{dt}{(\sigma-1)^2+t^2}.$$
So that
$$u(\sigma)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{(ab)^\sigma}\frac{\pi e^{-(\sigma-1)|\log(b/a)|}}{\sigma-1},$$
$$u(\sigma)-\frac{1}{2\zeta(\sigma)^2(\sigma-1)}=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{(ab)^\sigma}\frac{e^{-(\sigma-1)|\log(b/a)|}-1}{\sigma-1},$$
and
$$u(\sigma)-\frac{1}{2\zeta(\sigma)^2(\sigma-1)}=-
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{(ab)^\sigma}
|\log(b/a)|\int_0^1 e^{-(\sigma-1)|\log(b/a)|x}\,dx.$$
It is not easy here to justify to take limit for $\sigma\to1^+$ term by term, but if correct we will get
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{ab}
|\log(b/a)|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n}.$$
With
$$f(n):=-\frac12\sum_{ab=n}\mu(a)\mu(b)|\log(b/a)|.$$
The function $f(n)=0$ except if $n=mk^2$ with $|\mu(mk)|=1$. In this case
$f(n)=f(m)$. For $m$ squarefree $f(m)$ have the sign of $-\mu(m)$ multiplied by a logarithm of a number with prime divisors dividing $m$. But this number depends of the relative size of the divisors of $m$. For example with $p<q<r$ primes $f(pqr)$ can be equal to $2\log (pqr)$ or $3\log r$ according to $pq>r$ or $pq<r$.

Comment: Interesting! Does this check out numerically?

Comment: Your expression for $I$ can also be written as $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \check{m}(a)$, where $\check{m}(a) = \sum_{m\leq a} \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \log \frac{a}{m}$. Since $\check{m}(a) = 1 + O((\log a)^{-C})$, it is clear that the sum converges.

Comment: @Helfgott I computed the integral aproximately with Mathematica for $2\times 10^{-6}<|t|<2\times 10^6$ obtaining $0.81492827$ and then my sum oscillates, but the mean of the sums to 300000 give me the value $0.814346$. This is not too good, it is what I can say.

Comment: @Helfgott When I say the sum oscillates, it oscillates around 0.8 say, so that I took the mean of the sums to get an idea of the possible limit.

Comment: I'd expect $\sum_{n\leq x} (\mu(n)/n) \widehat{m}(a)$ to converge more quickly, but not necessarily more quickly than $O(1/\sqrt{x})$.